# How to use Canon's CanoScan LiDE 90 scanner in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, usb, scanner, canon, sane

I have an old **Canon LiDE 90 scanner** that works with no problem under Windows 7. Currently I am in a process of switching from Windows (7) to Ubuntu (18.10). One of my problems is that I cannot use my scanner in Ubuntu. When I connect this scanner to Ubuntu it is not recognized by the scanner software that comes with Ubuntu. I know that my scanner is not supported by the Sane Project in Linux: http://www.sane-project.org/unsupported/canon-lide-90.html

I tried to use it under *Wine*, but I was not able to install the Windows drivers and the application software coming with the scanner: both give errors during installation.

The `lsusb` output for this scanner is:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04a9:1900 Canon, Inc. CanoScan LiDE 90
```

The last lines relevant to this device as output by `sane-find-scanner -v -v` command are like this:

```
<This USB chip looks like a GL842 (result from sane-backends 1.0.27)>

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x1900 [CanoScan], chip=GL842) at libusb:001:006
```

Is there any workaround that I can use?

Comment: It seems that the only solution is to run a virtualized old Windows OS. (I installed _VirtualBox_ to my Ubuntu notebook and on top of it _Windows XP in a virtual machine_. After installing the driver and software which I downloaded from Canon's web site, I was able to use my scanner as usual.)

Comment: You can post your comment as answer instead, since it somehow solved your problem. Even accepting it as the right answer is possible and somewhat encouraged, since others might search this question with the focus on answered and accepted once. If a better solution is added later by someone else, you may still change your mind.

Comment: I am not sure whether this should be accepted as a **solution**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Canon LiDE 90 scanner** works in Ubuntu 20.10 (groovy). Previous versions of Ubuntu did not have support for this scanner. With [SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/) being upgraded to version 1.0.31, you can use this scanner with GUI utilities like `simple-scan`.

However, my comment above (to run the Canon utility in a virtualized old Windows OS) still is my preferred method. With this method you are using the real software from Canon and thus you can fully utilize the potential of this scanner.

Ref: http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html